# Unable to get jdbc connection between snowflake and spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get somw data from Snowflake but while configuring datasouce i am facing connection timeout error

Below is my datasource used to get connection

```
 @Primary
 @Bean public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException { 
 BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
 dataSource.setDriverClassName("net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver");
 dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:snowflake://<account>.snowflakecomputing.com/?warehouse=<warehouse>&database=<database>&schema=<schema>"); 
 dataSource.setUsername(username);
 dataSource.setPassword(password);
 return dataSource; 
}
```

Below is the error I am getting while trying to get connection

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered for HTTP request: Connect to <account>.snowflakecomputing.com:443 <account>.snowflakecomputing.com/3.136.103.32, <account>.snowflakecomputing.com/18.118.91.6, <account>.snowflakecomputing.com/3.130.158.108] failed: Connection timed out: connect.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:653)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:531)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:731)
    at com.cat.cso.indexoptimizesp.serviceImpl.IndexOptimizeServiceImpl.executesp(IndexOptimizeServiceImpl.java:30)
    at com.cat.cso.indexoptimizesp.CsoIndexOptimizeSpApplication.run(CsoIndexOptimizeSpApplication.java:39)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:782)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at com.cat.cso.indexoptimizesp.CsoIndexOptimizeSpApplication.main(CsoIndexOptimizeSpApplication.java:31)
Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered for HTTP request: Connect to <account>.snowflakecomputing.com:443 [<account>.snowflakecomputing.com/3.136.103.32, <account>.snowflakecomputing.com/18.118.91.6, <account>.snowflakecomputing.com/3.130.158.108] failed: Connection timed out: connect.
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.RestRequest.execute(RestRequest.java:284)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil.executeRequestInternal(HttpUtil.java:496)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil.executeRequest(HttpUtil.java:441)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil.executeGeneralRequest(HttpUtil.java:408)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.newSession(SessionUtil.java:586)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.openSession(SessionUtil.java:284)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFSession.open(SFSession.java:435)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initialize(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:104)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initializeConnection(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:79)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.initConnectionWithImpl(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:116)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.<init>(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:96)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver.connect(SnowflakeDriver.java:164)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:374)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:649)
    ... 10 more
```

Kindly help me with the solution

Answer (score 1):

Ty using **SnowflakeConnectionPoolDataSource** instead of **BasicDataSource**. You can also use **DataSourceBuilder** to build the DataSource from properties (application.yml) starting with *spring.datasource.snowflake* prefix:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    snowflake:
      url: jdbc:snowflake://<account>.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=<database>&role=<role>&warehouse=<warehouse>
      user: <user>
      password: <password>
```

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;


import net.snowflake.client.pooling.SnowflakeConnectionPoolDataSource;

@Configuration
public class DatasourcesConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.snowflake")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(SnowflakeConnectionPoolDataSource.class).build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection timeout typically means that there is something wrong with network config and JDBC driver cannot reach Snowflake server. The typical cause is proxy setting or TLS handshake issue. However, to know the exact cause, you'd better enable network logging in java to see what's going on with network. Set this property:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```